# Stop a web page from scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, dom-events

I am looking for a way to keep my web pages from scrolling. 
I am looking for solution based on JavaScript or jQuery events.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable scrolling by setting `overflow` css property to hidden in the page `body` element, like so:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you want to do it from jquery, you can do the equivalent:

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

Comment: When  i use a property overflow, i can't click on the elements of page.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use css fixed positioning and position things relative to the viewport.

Comment: This is an example of what I want to do: community.saucony.com/kinvara3

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you are trying to achieve exactly, you could put everything in a div, say #wrapper, and use some CSS:

```
#wrapper {
width: 950px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 550px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is an example of what I want to do: http://community.saucony.com/kinvara3/